# QMediaPlayer on Meego cannot play file from qrc resource file

Tags: qt, filesystems, meego

there are some said that QMediaPlayer cannot play file from .qrc (resource file) .
so I think there must be a workaround to play the file. I'm thinking about putting the file to the memory and play through it. but I dont know how to access it. I don't understand about meego file directory structure?

can you help me to understand about this?